# Java: Deserialize a json to object in rest template using "@class" in json -SpringBoot

Tags: java, jackson, spring-boot, deserialization, resttemplate

I have to instantiate a class which extends the abstract class from JSON using information in @class as shown below.

```
"name": {
  "health": "xxx",
  "animal": {
    "_class": "com.example.Dog",
    "height" : "20"
    "color" : "white"
  }
},
```

Here the abstract class is animal and dog extends the animal class. So using the information in @class, can we instantiate dog directly. Also this is the response I am getting in restTemplate

```
ResponseEntity<List<SomeListName>> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://10.150.15.172:8080/agencies", HttpMethod.GET, request, responseType);
```

The following error is coming when this line is executed.
Since the POJO classes are auto-generated, I cannot use annotations like **@JsonTypeInfo**

I am using Spring boot and maven.
This error is coming in console.

> Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of "MyPOJO", problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation regardless of the fact that the classes are generated, by adhering to [MixIn's](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

> "mix-in annotations are": a way to associate annotations with 
>   classes, without modifying (target) classes themselves.
>
> That is, you can:
>
> Define that annotations of a mix-in class (or interface) will be used
>   with a target class (or interface) such that it appears as if the
>   target class had all annotations that the mix-in class has (for
>   purposes of configuring serialization / deserialization)

So you can write your `AnimalMixIn` class, something like

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "_class")  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "com.example.Cat"),  
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "com.example.Dog") })  
abstract class AnimalMixIn  
{  

}
```

and configure your deserializer

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(  
    Animal.class, AnimalMixIn.class);
```

Since you're using Spring Boot, you can check the following blog post to see how you can customize the ObjectMapper for using the MixIns, [Customizing the Jackson Object Mapper](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#customizing-the-jackson-objectmapper), note especially the [mixIn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html#mixIn-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) method of `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`

Using customized `ObjectMapper` within `RestTemplate` should be set through converters, something like

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    return restTemplate;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But since i am using spring boot, Do I have to use any custom object mappers which will replace HttpMessageConverter's default object mapper in restTemplate.

Comment: You welcome, yes, you'll have to customize the default object mapper, I've provided some references in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to the answer from @Master Slave. He said

> you can customize the ObjectMapper for using the MixIns, Customizing the Jackson Object Mapper, note especially the mixIn method of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

but he didn't define the `ObjectMapper` for the `RestTemplate`. Here is how his answer helped me to figure out my complete answer.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(Target.class, MixinClass.class)
    .setVisibility(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance()
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
        .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    );
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
MyResponse response =
    restTemplate.exchange(request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MyResponse>() {
    }).getBody();
```