# How can I access Spring ConfigurationProperties inside a custom JsonDeserializer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a custom Json Deserializer that I am trying to Autowire ConfigurationProperties into. However, the property is always null. I tried using the `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` but for some reason the `CurrentWebApplicationContext` is null.

How can I get the `@Autowired` to work in my custom deserializer?

**Update:**

I am using `@JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)` on my domain class, which is be utilized through a `RestTemplate` call in a service class.

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.

**HealthDeserializer**

```
public class HealthDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Health> {  
    @Autowired
    private HealthMappings mappings;   
    @Override
    public Health deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        mappings.lookup(...);
    }
}
```

**HealthMappings**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="health_mapping")
public class HealthMappings {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide further information, e.g. the implementation of the JSON Deserializer? How do you instantiate the deserializer? It's hard to help you with the given information.

Comment: I've updated with a few more bits of information to help explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I did a little bit of research and it seems like you can "manually" set deserializer objects in the rest template. Like that you can't use the annotations in your domain objects any more but might be a solution for your problem. Will dig into that tonight but will take me a few hours until I have the time to do so. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527640/java-deserialize-a-json-to-object-in-rest-template-using-class-in-json-spri

Comment: I tried looking at the solution that you suggested, and I wasn't thrilled with the idea of messing around with the default ObjectMapper instance, so instead I had my Deserializer implement `ApplicationContextAware` and let the deserializer access the beans that way. Not ideal, but it works just fine.