# Calling rest service with Spring Rest template

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a service that calls consumes a specific URL. I have a class for the items and another class for the specific fields in the items. One of the fields is an array and I need to access it.

```
"items"[{
  "success":true,
  "publicKey":"dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W",
  "stream":{
    "_doc":{
      "tags":[
        "battery",
        "humidity",
        "light",
        "pressure",
        "rain",
        "temperature",
        "weather",
        "wind"
      ]
      "date":"2014-04-05T14:37:39.441Z",
      "last_push":"2014-09-12T18:22:26.252Z",
      "hidden":false,
      "flagged":false,
      "alias":"wimp_weather",
      "location":{
        "long":"Boulder, CO, United States",
        "city":"Boulder",
        "state":"Colorado",
        "country":"United States",
        "lat":"40.0149856",
        "lng":"-105.27054559999999"
      },
      "title":"Wimp Weather Station",
      "description":"Weather station on top my roof. Read the full tutorial here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/weather-station-wirelessly-connected-to-wunderground",
      "__v":0,
      "_id":"534015331ebf49e11af8059d"
    },
  }
]
}
```

I'm trying to get success, publicKey and location. But the result is:

```
{"success":true,"publicKey":"dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W","location":null}
```

I use this method to retrieve the result

```
@RequestMapping("/weather")
public ResponseEntity result() {

    WeatherPOJO result = weatherService.fetchWeather();
    return new ResponseEntity(result.getItems().get(0), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And this is the class that fetches the url

```
public WeatherPOJO fetchWeather() {
    WeatherPOJO rest = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "https://data.sparkfun.com/streams/dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W.json"
            , WeatherPOJO.class);
    return rest;
}
```

WeatherItem class

```
package com.example.services;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class WeatherItem {

    private boolean success;
    private String publicKey;
    private String location;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }


    public String getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public void setPublicKey(String publicKey) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

WeatherPOJO

```
package com.example.services;

import java.util.List;

public class WeatherPOJO {

    private List<WeatherItem> items;

    public List<WeatherItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<WeatherItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Why can't I reach the location value?

Comment: Could you please add the Java class that corresponds to the `location` field in your JSON?

Comment: Also, you may be interested in [the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30528321/3465375)

Comment: @SirCelsius I've added all the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because location is nested further down.  Try adding this to your `WeatherItem`:

```
@JsonProperty("stream")
public void setStream(Map<String, Object> nested) {
    this.location = nested.get("_doc").get("location").get("long");
}
```

Of course this will only get you the long name of the location into your location variable location.  If you want all the fields then create a bean with them and then map the entire location object

```
private Location location;
...

@JsonProperty("stream")
public void setStream(Map<String, Object> nested) {
    Map<String, Object> loc = nested.get("_doc").get("location");
    this.location = new Location();
    this.location.setCity(loc.get("city"));
    ....
}
```

Of course the easiest thing would be to match your pojo to the structure (unrelated properties/getters/setters left out for brevity):

```
class WeatherItem {
    Stream stream;
}
class Stream {
    Doc _doc;
}
class Doc {
    Location location;
}
class Location {
    String city;
    Double lat;
    Double lon;
    ....
}
```

Comment: this.location = nested.get("_doc").get("location").get("long"); This does not work. I can only add one .get.

Comment: And what is returned?

Comment: I used the last solution. And created different pojos for the different levels of items in the json file. Thank you @DeezCashews.

Comment: I know it's a pain. A feature request has been in for some time now to support mapping nested items through annotations but it's been out there for years now.

Comment: lol it really is a pain. I have another question, let's say I want to add my own field to the json resonse. Let's say I want to add continent. Continent would depend on the country field value right? So how do I extract the country value only and assign it to continent and then display it in the json result?

Comment: Ask another question providing some context. That way this question doesn't become cluttered and  you'll have more eyes helping you.